# VSFTPD Debian настройка

Tags: debian, ftp, камера, web-camera

Имеется *IP*-камера, на ней настроена *FTP* запись на сервер. Сервер сам - *Debian*. *FTP* - *vsftpd*. 
Прилагаю конфиг:

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
#
# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=YES
listen_port=20
#
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. By default, listening
# on the IPv6 "any" address (::) will accept connections from both IPv6
# and IPv4 clients. It is not necessary to listen on *both* IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets. If you want that (perhaps because you want to listen on specific
# addresses) then you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration
# files.
listen_ipv6=NO
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default).
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
local_umask=022
file_open_mode=0777
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
anon_upload_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=NO
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=NO
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
log_ftp_protocol=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=sifon4ik
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
ascii_upload_enable=YES
ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
#chroot_local_user=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/user_conf
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO

userlist_deny=NO

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=10090
pasv_max_port=10100
max_per_ip=30
ftp_username=ftpforce_dot_files=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
#listen_address=1.2.3.4
#hide_file=
#anon_max_rate=
local_max_rate=0
```

При попытке записи на сервер валятся вот такие логи:

```
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11746] CONNECT: Client "1.2.3.4"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11746] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "220 Welcome to blah FTP service."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11746] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "USER sifon4ik"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11746] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "331 Please specify the password."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11746] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "PASS <password>"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11745] [sifon4ik] OK LOGIN: Client "1.2.3.4"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "REST 0"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "350 Restart position accepted (0)."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "ALLO 1048576"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "202 ALLO command ignored."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "CWD /var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "250 Directory successfully changed."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "ALLO 1048576"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "202 ALLO command ignored."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "ALLO 1048576"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "202 ALLO command ignored."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "CWD /var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "250 Directory successfully changed."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "ALLO 1048576"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "202 ALLO command ignored."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "230 Login successful."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "PWD"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "257 "/var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik""
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "CWD /var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "250 Directory successfully changed."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "PWD"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "257 "/var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik""
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "CWD /var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "250 Directory successfully changed."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "CWD Activecam/2015-09-24/001/dav/22"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "250 Directory successfully changed."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "CWD /Activecam/2015-09-24/001/dav/22"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "550 Failed to change directory."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "CWD Activecam/2015-09-24/001/dav/22"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "550 Failed to change directory."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "QUIT"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11747] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "221 Goodbye."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "TYPE I"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "200 Switching to Binary mode."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "PWD"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "257 "/var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik""
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "CWD /var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "250 Directory successfully changed."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "SIZE /Activecam/2015-09-24/001/dav/22/22.07.39-22.07.39[R][0@0][0].dav_"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "550 Could not get file size."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "SIZE Activecam/2015-09-24/001/dav/22/22.07.39-22.07.39[R][0@0][0].dav_"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "550 Could not get file size."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "CWD /var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "250 Directory successfully changed."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "PWD"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "257 "/var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik""
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "CWD /var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "250 Directory successfully changed."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "DELE /Activecam/2015-09-24/001/dav/22/22.07.39-22.07.39[R][0@0][0].idx_"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "550 Delete operation failed."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FAIL DELETE: Client "1.2.3.4 "/Activecam/2015-09-24/001/dav/22/22.07.39-22.07.39[R][0@0][0].idx_"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "DELE Activecam/2015-09-24/001/dav/22/22.07.39-22.07.39[R][0@0][0].idx_"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "550 Delete operation failed."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FAIL DELETE: Client "1.2.3.4 "/var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik/Activecam/2015-09-24/001/dav/22/22.07.39-22.07.39[R][0@0][0].idx_"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "CWD /var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "250 Directory successfully changed."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "ALLO 1048576"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "202 ALLO command ignored."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "CWD /var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "250 Directory successfully changed."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "ALLO 1048576"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "202 ALLO command ignored."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "ALLO 1048576"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "202 ALLO command ignored."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "CWD /var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "250 Directory successfully changed."
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4 "ALLO 1048576"
Thu Sep 24 22:07:43 2015 [pid 11708] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4 "202 ALLO command ignored."
```

Как это исправить?

p.s.

```
Thu Sep 24 23:15:44 2015 [pid 25386] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4", "250 Directory successfully changed."
Thu Sep 24 23:15:44 2015 [pid 25386] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4", "SIZE /Activecam/2015-09-24/001/dav/23/23.15.38-23.15.38[R][0@0][0].dav_"
Thu Sep 24 23:15:44 2015 [pid 25386] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4", "550 Could not get file size."
Thu Sep 24 23:15:44 2015 [pid 25386] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4", "SIZE Activecam/2015-09-24/001/dav/23/23.15.38-23.15.38[R][0@0][0].dav_"
Thu Sep 24 23:15:44 2015 [pid 25386] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4", "550 Could not get file size."
Thu Sep 24 23:15:44 2015 [pid 25386] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4", "CWD /var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik/Activecam/2015-09-24/001/dav/23"
Thu Sep 24 23:15:44 2015 [pid 25386] [sifon4ik] FTP response: Client "1.2.3.4", "250 Directory successfully changed."
Thu Sep 24 23:15:44 2015 [pid 25386] [sifon4ik] FTP command: Client "1.2.3.4", "PWD"
```

Comment: а какому пользователю принадлежит каталог `/var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik` и всё его содержимое?

Comment: это пользователю и принадлежит. sifon4ik:ftp

Comment: пользователь, судя по логу, пытается удалить какие-то файлы в каталоге `/var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik/Activecam/2015-09-24/001/dav/22/`, а сервер отвечает, что не может этого сделать. проверьте права и принадлежность самого этого каталога и его содержимого. // `ftp_username=ftpforce_dot_files=YES` — тут, видимо, должно быть две строки, а не одна.

Comment: Хм....

root@gs:/var/ftp/cams/sifon4ik# ls -ln
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 1008 118 4096 Sep 24 23:08 Activecam